# android RelativeLayout change height programmatically

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I try change layout height programmatically. I have two buttons. In one button I change my layout position and second button I try to receive save position witch I was first time.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/popaplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >
```

This is a my layout 
and in first button I wrote

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.movies_title_layout);
scrollpopap.setLayoutParams(parms);
scrollpopap.setScrollingEnabled(true);
```

and second button

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300);
rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
scrollpopap.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
scrollpopap.setScrollingEnabled(false);
```

In `xml` file I wrote height 200dp and programmatically 300 and there are different height. How I can  wrote save height in programmatically?

if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First convert *200 dp* into pixels -

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (200 * scale + 0.5f);
```

Then set programatically,

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, pixels);
            rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            scrollpopap.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
            scrollpopap.setScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: If i have a child inside RelativeLayout with match_parent in width and modify the width from RelativeLayout, how can update the width of child?

Answer (score 32):

Convert DP to PX like this.

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int px = (int) (100 * scale + 0.5f);  // replace 100 with your dimensions
```

Set Some layout_gravity of relative layout. and Change height and width by java code.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
rl.getLayoutParams().height = px;  
rl.getLayoutParams().width = px;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you intending to change `RelativeLayout` height, then this help.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
relativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
relativeLayout.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

Answer (score 6):

**Use this**

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout_id);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 320;
params.width = 320;
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Kotlin** Users who want to set **Height & Width from Dimens file**, use this:

```
relativeLayout.layoutParams.width = relativeLayout.context
                    .resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width)

relativeLayout.layoutParams.height = relativeLayout.context
                    .resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height)
```